# pandas merging 2 dataframes of difference size, columns and freq

Tags: arrays, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, merge

I've been trying to merge 2 NFL dataframes of different sizes and freq,but 2 same same columns of teiamname and year, the first one the index is team name and year, and are the year avgs, the next one is sorted by tm name and year but is broken into weekly games 1-17, so I've been trying to merge on the team name and year then give the yearly avgs,which is 9 columns and then per that year per week(1-17) on 11 different columns.  I have been at this for 2 weeks, iv tried every which way, multi indexing, ... I can iterate through each datframe and append to an array in the right order but when I try to make that list a DF.. no go, tried multi indexing groupby....

any help would be greatly appreciated
Thanks

```
       Year  Tm_name    W     L   W_L_Pct   PD     MoV  SoS   SRS  OSRS  DSRS
1  2015     1     13.0   3.0   0.813   176.0  11.0  1.3  12.3   9.0   3.4
2  2016     1      7.0   8.0   0.469    56.0   3.5 -1.9   1.6   2.4  -0.8
3  2017     1      8.0   8.0   0.500   -66.0  -4.1  0.4  -3.7  -4.0   0.2
4  2018     1      3.0  13.0   0.188  -200.0 -12.5  1.0 -11.5  -9.6  -1.9
5  2015     2      8.0   8.0   0.500    -6.0  -0.4 -3.4  -3.8  -4.0   0.3
  Week  Year    Date     Tm_name  win_loss  home_away  Opp1_team  Tm_Pnts  \
0   1   2018 2018-09-09     1        0.0       1.0       32.0       6.0     
1   2   2018 2018-09-16     1        0.0       0.0       18.0       0.0     
2   3   2018 2018-09-23     1        0.0       1.0        6.0      14.0     
3   4   2018 2018-09-30     1        0.0       1.0       28.0      17.0     
4   5   2018 2018-10-07     1        1.0       0.0       29.0      28.0     

   Opp2_pnts  Off_1stD  Off_TotYd  Def_1stD_All  Def_TotYd_All  
0    24.0       14.0      213.0        30.0          429.0      
1    34.0        5.0      137.0        24.0          432.0      
2    16.0       13.0      221.0        21.0          316.0      
3    20.0       18.0      263.0        19.0          331.0      
4    18.0       10.0      220.0        33.0          447.0
```

Comment: Go through https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve before posting a question.

Comment: Please describe your input dataframe & output dataframe expectation clearly, see other posts tagged with `pandas` to know more, also you might wanna go through https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: these are the 2 DF.head()s Im trying to merge, DF 1 each of the 32 teams have years of avgs2018-2015. DF2 each 32teams has 17 weeks of game stats through 2018-2015, im trying to merge them so I don't have any NAN data or related rows,ive been through stack and the documentation either I don't understand it or its not there or specific enough to my cause

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. I can tell that you put a lot of effort into writing your question, but unfortunately as currently worded it's quite confusing. A lot of the textual information is hard to follow: you'd be much likelier to get an answer if you provide a small *sample* of your data, showing input and desired output. Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

If you have 2 columns which are the same in both dataframes, why don't you use pandas.Dataframe.join to join the two tables? By that you would have all data for the team name and year in the same row.

Comment: from df1 it row 17 times instead of just doing df1 row for that unfollowed by the 17 rows/games("week")for that team and yr from df2. if I drop dup. organize the cols&rows wrong it list all the df1 rows for each tm/yr 1st(which is kind of what I wanted but  it goes through all week 1 games for 32 teams for per year, then does 32 teams for4 years for week 2, no matter how I try I can't organize it, its only 126 rows which I guess there should be bc there is 32 teams times 4 years when it should be around2000, maybe im wrong, I can't visualize it, I need to see how it looks not truncated by Atom

Comment: okay, I am still struggling to understand what your goal is.
You have 1DF with the averages calculated and 1DF with 17 weeks of stats for the same number of years. Is the NFL season 17 weeks long?
And what should the output look like?
all weeks plus the average for each year and team?

Comment: hierarchal index broken into 3 levels with tuples                                             lvl_00 = result.Tm_name.values
lt2.Off_1stD.values, result2.Off_TotYd.values, result2.Def_1stD_All.values, result2.Def_TotYd_All.values))

Comment: lvl_01 = (result.Year.values, (result.W.values, result.L.values, result.W_L_Pct.values, result.PD.values,
                               result.MoV.values, result.SoS.values, result.SRS.values, result.OSRS.values, result.DSRS.values))
lvl_02 = (result2.Week.values, (result2.Date.values, result2.win_loss.values, result2.home_away.values, result2.Opp1_team.values, result2.Tm_Pnts.values,
                                result2.Opp2_pnts.values, result

Comment: I asked the same question: bc I was told this one wasn't descriptive enough so at this url I added the code and DF's if you think it would help. [link]https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54239560/pandas-merging-dfs-that-have-diff-size-shape-and-column-names-and-freq-with-no.