# Pandas merging DF's that have diff size shape and column names and freq with no duplicates

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Pandas merging DF's that have 2 columns in common their index(team name(32 teams), year 2018-2015); DF1 has 9 columns of yearly Team NFL stats AVG's, DF2 has same index team(32) and year(2018-2015) but has 11 columns of diff stats for each of the 17games(or "weeks")::: so im trying to merge for every team and year it prints the yearly avgs 1st or (Df1's 9columns,in a row) for that team and year, followed by DF2's each of its 11 columns of stats per 17(ROWS)-- games ("weeks") on its index of each team and year.

```
lvl0 = result.Tm_name.values
lvl1 = result.Year.values
newidx = pd.MultiIndex.from_arrays([lvl0, lvl1], names = ["Tm_name", "Year"])
result.set_index(newidx, inplace = True)
result.drop(["Year", "Tm_name"], axis = 1, inplace = True)
print(result)


                W     L   W_L_Pct   PD     MoV  SoS   SRS  OSRS  DSRS
Tm_name Year                                                         
1       2015  13.0   3.0   0.813   176.0  11.0  1.3  12.3   9.0   3.4
        2016   7.0   8.0   0.469    56.0   3.5 -1.9   1.6   2.4  -0.8
        2017   8.0   8.0   0.500   -66.0  -4.1  0.4  -3.7  -4.0   0.2
        2018   3.0  13.0   0.188  -200.0 -12.5  1.0 -11.5  -9.6  -1.9
2       2015   8.0   8.0   0.500    -6.0  -0.4 -3.4  -3.8  -4.0   0.3
        2016  11.0   5.0   0.688   134.0   8.4  0.1   8.5  10.5  -2.0
        2017  10.0   6.0   0.625    38.0   2.4  1.9   4.3   1.1   3.2
        2018   7.0   9.0   0.438    -9.0  -0.6  0.4  -0.1   2.5  -2.6
3       2015   5.0  11.0   0.313   -73.0  -4.6  2.6  -1.9  -0.7  -1.2
        2016   8.0   8.0   0.500    22.0   1.4  0.2   1.5  -1.1   2.6
        2017   9.0   7.0   0.563    92.0   5.8 -2.4   3.4   2.2   1.2
        2018  10.0   6.0   0.625   102.0   6.4  0.6   7.0   0.6   6.4
4       2015   8.0   8.0   0.500    20.0   1.3 -1.2   0.0   0.3  -0.2
        2016   7.0   9.0   0.438    21.0   1.3 -1.6  -0.3   1.8  -2.2
        2017   9.0   7.0   0.563   -57.0  -3.6 -0.5  -4.0  -3.0  -1.0
        2018   6.0  10.0   0.375  -105.0  -6.6 -0.3  -6.9  -6.3  -0.6
5       2015  15.0   1.0   0.938   192.0  12.0 -3.9   8.1   6.0   2.1
        2016   6.0  10.0   0.375   -33.0  -2.1  1.1  -1.0  -0.2  -0.8
        2017  11.0   5.0   0.688    36.0   2.3  2.1   4.3   1.7   2.7
        2018   7.0   9.0   0.438    -6.0  -0.4  1.3   0.9   0.1   0.8
6       2015   6.0  10.0   0.375   -62.0  -3.9  2.6  -1.3  -0.1  -1.2
        2016   3.0  13.0   0.188  -120.0  -7.5  0.0  -7.5  -5.2  -2.3
        2017   5.0  11.0   0.313   -56.0  -3.5  2.2  -1.3  -4.6   3.3
        2018  12.0   4.0   0.750   138.0   8.6 -2.3   6.3   1.5   4.8
7       2015  12.0   4.0   0.750   140.0   8.8  1.9  10.6   4.8   5.8


lvl_0 = result2.Tm_name.values
lvl_1 = result2.Year.values
newidx_2 = newidx = pd.MultiIndex.from_arrays([lvl_0, lvl_1], names=["Tm_name", "Year"])
result2.set_index(newidx, inplace=True)
result2.drop(["Year", "Tm_name"], axis=1, inplace=True)
print(result2)

             Week    Date     win_loss  home_away  Opp1_team  Tm_Pnts  \
Tm_name Year                                                            
1       2018   1  2018-09-09     0.0       1.0       32.0       6.0     
        2018   2  2018-09-16     0.0       0.0       18.0       0.0     
        2018   3  2018-09-23     0.0       1.0        6.0      14.0     
        2018   4  2018-09-30     0.0       1.0       28.0      17.0     
        2018   5  2018-10-07     1.0       0.0       29.0      28.0     
        2018   6  2018-10-14     0.0       0.0       20.0      17.0     
        2018   7  2018-10-18     0.0       1.0       10.0      10.0     
        2018   8  2018-10-28     1.0       1.0       29.0      18.0     
        2018  10  2018-11-11     0.0       0.0       16.0      14.0     
        2018  11  2018-11-18     0.0       1.0       25.0      21.0     
        2018  12  2018-11-25     0.0       0.0       17.0      10.0     
        2018  13  2018-12-02     1.0       0.0       12.0      20.0     
        2018  14  2018-12-09     0.0       1.0       11.0       3.0     
        2018  15  2018-12-16     0.0       0.0        2.0      14.0     
        2018  16  2018-12-23     0.0       1.0       18.0       9.0     
        2018  17  2018-12-30     0.0       0.0       28.0      24.0     
        2017   1  2017-09-10     0.0       0.0       11.0      23.0     
        2017   2  2017-09-17     1.0       0.0       14.0      16.0     
        2017   3  2017-09-25     0.0       1.0        9.0      17.0     
        2017   4  2017-10-01     1.0       1.0       29.0      18.0     
        2017   5  2017-10-08     0.0       0.0       26.0       7.0     
        2017   6  2017-10-15     1.0       1.0       30.0      38.0     
        2017   7  2017-10-22     0.0       0.0       18.0       0.0     
        2017   9  2017-11-05     1.0       0.0       29.0      20.0     
        2017  10  2017-11-09     0.0       1.0       28.0      16.0     
        2017  11  2017-11-19     0.0       0.0       13.0      21.0     
        2017  12  2017-11-26     1.0       1.0       15.0      27.0     
        2017  13  2017-12-03     0.0       1.0       18.0      16.0     
        2017  14  2017-12-10     1.0       1.0       31.0      12.0     
        2017  15  2017-12-17     0.0       0.0       32.0      15.0     
...           ...        ...       ...        ...        ...      ...   
        2016   5  2016-10-06     1.0       0.0       29.0      33.0     
        2016   6  2016-10-17     1.0       1.0       24.0      28.0     
        2016   7  2016-10-23     NaN       1.0       28.0       6.0     
        2016   8  2016-10-30     0.0       0.0        5.0      20.0     
        2016  10  2016-11-13     1.0       1.0       29.0      23.0     
        2016  11  2016-11-20     0.0       0.0       20.0      24.0     
        2016  12  2016-11-27     0.0       0.0        2.0      19.0     
        2016  13  2016-12-04     1.0       1.0       32.0      31.0     
        2016  14  2016-12-11     0.0       0.0       19.0      23.0     
        2016  15  2016-12-18     0.0       1.0       22.0      41.0     
        2016  16  2016-12-24     1.0       0.0       28.0      34.0     
        2016  17  2016-01-01     1.0       0.0       18.0      44.0     
        2015   1  2015-09-13     1.0       1.0       22.0      31.0     
        2015   2  2015-09-20     1.0       0.0        6.0      48.0     
        2015   3  2015-09-27     1.0       1.0       29.0      47.0     
        2015   4  2015-10-04     0.0       1.0        NaN      22.0     
        2015   5  2015-10-11     1.0       0.0       11.0      42.0     
        2015   6  2015-10-18     0.0       0.0       27.0      13.0     
        2015   7  2015-10-26     1.0       1.0        3.0      26.0     
        2015   8  2015-11-01     1.0       0.0        8.0      34.0     
        2015  10  2015-11-15     1.0       0.0       28.0      39.0     
        2015  11  2015-11-22     1.0       1.0        7.0      34.0     
        2015  12  2015-11-29     1.0       0.0       29.0      19.0     
        2015  13  2015-12-06     1.0       0.0        NaN      27.0     
        2015  14  2015-12-10     1.0       1.0       20.0      23.0     
        2015  15  2015-12-20     1.0       0.0       26.0      40.0     
        2015  16  2015-12-27     1.0       1.0       12.0      38.0     
        2015  17  2015-01-03     0.0       1.0       28.0       6.0     
2       2018   1  2018-09-06     0.0       0.0       26.0      12.0     
        2018   2  2018-09-16     1.0       1.0        5.0      31.0     

              Opp2_pnts  Off_1stD  Off_TotYd  Def_1stD_All  Def_TotYd_All  
Tm_name Year                                                               
1       2018    24.0       14.0      213.0        30.0          429.0      
        2018    34.0        5.0      137.0        24.0          432.0      
        2018    16.0       13.0      221.0        21.0          316.0      
        2018    20.0       18.0      263.0        19.0          331.0      
        2018    18.0       10.0      220.0        33.0          447.0      
        2018    27.0       16.0      268.0        20.0          411.0      
        2018    45.0       14.0      223.0        15.0          309.0      
        2018    15.0       20.0      321.0        16.0          267.0      
        2018    26.0       21.0      260.0        20.0          330.0      
        2018    23.0       13.0      282.0        19.0          325.0      
        2018    45.0       10.0      149.0        30.0          414.0      
        2018    17.0       18.0      315.0        22.0          325.0      
        2018    17.0       22.0      279.0        16.0          218.0      
        2018    40.0       18.0      253.0        23.0          435.0      
        2018    31.0       15.0      263.0        33.0          461.0      
        2018    27.0       12.0      198.0        16.0          291.0      
        2017    35.0       24.0      308.0        19.0          367.0      
        2017    13.0       17.0      389.0        18.0          266.0      
        2017    28.0       22.0      332.0        15.0          273.0      
        2017    15.0       25.0      368.0        20.0          305.0      
        2017    34.0       16.0      307.0        19.0          419.0      
        2017    33.0       23.0      432.0        21.0          412.0      
        2017    33.0       10.0      196.0        28.0          425.0      
        2017    10.0       20.0      368.0        17.0          329.0      
        2017    22.0       24.0      290.0        14.0          287.0      
        2017    31.0       17.0      292.0        22.0          357.0      
        2017    24.0       20.0      344.0        19.0          219.0      
        2017    32.0       19.0      305.0        18.0          303.0      
        2017     7.0       16.0      261.0        14.0          204.0      
        2017    20.0       19.0      286.0        14.0          218.0      
...                 ...       ...        ...           ...            ...  
        2016    21.0       17.0      288.0        25.0          286.0      
        2016     3.0       28.0      396.0        11.0          230.0      
        2016     6.0       23.0      443.0        11.0          257.0      
        2016    30.0       22.0      340.0        19.0          349.0      
        2016    20.0       26.0      443.0        15.0          281.0      
        2016    30.0       24.0      290.0        16.0          217.0      
        2016    38.0       23.0      332.0        28.0          360.0      
        2016    23.0       24.0      369.0        19.0          333.0      
        2016    26.0       21.0      300.0        15.0          314.0      
        2016    48.0       26.0      425.0        33.0          488.0      
        2016    31.0       21.0      370.0        24.0          391.0      
        2016     6.0       21.0      344.0         9.0          123.0      
        2015    19.0       25.0      427.0        18.0          408.0      
        2015    23.0       21.0      300.0        18.0          335.0      
        2015     7.0       28.0      446.0        10.0          156.0      
        2015    24.0       26.0      447.0        13.0          328.0      
        2015    17.0       15.0      345.0        29.0          435.0      
        2015    25.0       21.0      469.0        14.0          310.0      
        2015    18.0       21.0      414.0        18.0          276.0      
        2015    20.0       25.0      491.0        16.0          254.0      
        2015    32.0       30.0      451.0        18.0          343.0      
        2015    31.0       21.0      383.0        24.0          377.0      
        2015    13.0       26.0      337.0        17.0          368.0      
        2015     3.0       29.0      524.0         9.0          212.0      
        2015    20.0       22.0      393.0        23.0          389.0      
        2015    17.0       28.0      493.0        19.0          424.0      
        2015     8.0       19.0      381.0        16.0          178.0      
        2015    36.0       16.0      232.0        22.0          354.0      
2       2018    18.0       16.0      299.0        18.0          232.0      
        2018    24.0       23.0      442.0        27.0          439.0
```

--I can't just merge them I've tried many different ways, it never comes out right so I figured I can get into a list and make a dataframe from the array.  The array looks like what I want but when I put it into a dataframe, it will not do it{check below}

```
app = []

for row in result.itertuples():
    app.append(row)
    for row_1 in result2.itertuples():
        if row[0] == row_1[0]:
            app.append(row_1)

9.0, Off_1stD=25.0, Off_TotYd=427.0, Def_1stD_All=18.0, Def_TotYd_All=408.0)
Pandas(Index=(1, 2015), Week='2', Date=Timestamp('2015-09-20 00:00:00'), win_loss=1.0, home_away=0.0, Opp1_team=6.0, Tm_Pnts=48.0, Opp2_pnts=23.0, Off_1stD=21.0, Off_TotYd=300.0, Def_1stD_All=18.0, Def_TotYd_All=335.0)
Pandas(Index=(1, 2015), Week='3', Date=Timestamp('2015-09-27 00:00:00'), win_loss=1.0, home_away=1.0, Opp1_team=29.0, Tm_Pnts=47.0, Opp2_pnts=7.0, Off_1stD=28.0, Off_TotYd=446.0, Def_1stD_All=10.0, Def_TotYd_All=156.0)
Pandas(Index=(1, 2015), Week='4', Date=Timestamp('2015-10-04 00:00:00'), win_loss=0.0, home_away=1.0, Opp1_team=nan, Tm_Pnts=22.0, Opp2_pnts=24.0, Off_1stD=26.0, Off_TotYd=447.0, Def_1stD_All=13.0, Def_TotYd_All=328.0)
Pandas(Index=(1, 2015), Week='5', Date=Timestamp('2015-10-11 00:00:00'), win_loss=1.0, home_away=0.0, Opp1_team=11.0, Tm_Pnts=42.0, Opp2_pnts=17.0, Off_1stD=15.0, Off_TotYd=345.0, Def_1stD_All=29.0, Def_TotYd_All=435.0)
Pandas(Index=(1, 2015), Week='6', Date=Timestamp('2015-10-18 00:00:00'), win_loss=0.0, home_away=0.0, Opp1_team=27.0, Tm_Pnts=13.0, Opp2_pnts=25.0, Off_1stD=21.0, Off_TotYd=469.0, Def_1stD_All=14.0, Def_TotYd_All=310.0)
Pandas(Index=(1, 2015), Week='7', Date=Timestamp('2015-10-26 00:00:00'), win_loss=1.0, home_away=1.0, Opp1_team=3.0, Tm_Pnts=26.0, Opp2_pnts=18.0, Off_1stD=21.0, Off_TotYd=414.0, Def_1stD_All=18.0, Def_TotYd_All=276.0)
Pandas(Index=(1, 2015), Week='8', Date=Timestamp('2015-11-01 00:00:00'), win_loss=1.0, home_away=0.0, Opp1_team=8.0, Tm_Pnts=34.0, Opp2_pnts=20.0, Off_1stD=25.0, Off_TotYd=491.0, Def_1stD_All=16.0, Def_TotYd_All=254.0)
Pandas(Index=(1, 2015), Week='10', Date=Timestamp('2015-11-15 00:00:00'), win_loss=1.0, home_away=0.0, Opp1_team=28.0, Tm_Pnts=39.0, Opp2_pnts=32.0, Off_1stD=30.0, Off_TotYd=451.0, Def_1stD_All=18.0, Def_TotYd_All=343.0)
Pandas(Index=(1, 2015), Week='11', Date=Timestamp('2015-11-22 00:00:00'), win_loss=1.0, home_away=1.0, Opp1_team=7.0, Tm_Pnts=34.0, Opp2_pnts=31.0, Off_1stD=21.0, Off_TotYd=383.0, Def_1stD_All=24.0, Def_TotYd_All=377.0)
Pandas(Index=(1, 2015), Week='12', Date=Timestamp('2015-11-29 00:00:00'), win_loss=1.0, home_away=0.0, Opp1_team=29.0, Tm_Pnts=19.0, Opp2_pnts=13.0, Off_1stD=26.0, Off_TotYd=337.0, Def_1stD_All=17.0, Def_TotYd_All=368.0)
Pandas(Index=(1, 2015), Week='13', Date=Timestamp('2015-12-06 00:00:00'), win_loss=1.0, home_away=0.0, Opp1_team=nan, Tm_Pnts=27.0, Opp2_pnts=3.0, Off_1stD=29.0, Off_TotYd=524.0, Def_1stD_All=9.0, Def_TotYd_All=212.0)
Pandas(Index=(1, 2015), Week='14', Date=Timestamp('2015-12-10 00:00:00'), win_loss=1.0, home_away=1.0, Opp1_team=20.0, Tm_Pnts=23.0, Opp2_pnts=20.0, Off_1stD=22.0, Off_TotYd=393.0, Def_1stD_All=23.0, Def_TotYd_All=389.0)
Pandas(Index=(1, 2015), Week='15', Date=Timestamp('2015-12-20 00:00:00'), win_loss=1.0, home_away=0.0, Opp1_team=26.0, Tm_Pnts=40.0, Opp2_pnts=17.0, Off_1stD=28.0, Off_TotYd=493.0, Def_1stD_All=19.0, Def_TotYd_All=424.0)
Pandas(Index=(1, 2015), Week='16', Date=Timestamp('2015-12-27 00:00:00'), win_loss=1.0, home_away=1.0, Opp1_team=12.0, Tm_Pnts=38.0, Opp2_pnts=8.0, Off_1stD=19.0, Off_TotYd=381.0, Def_1stD_All=16.0, Def_TotYd_All=178.0)
Pandas(Index=(1, 2015), Week='17', Date=Timestamp('2015-01-03 00:00:00'), win_loss=0.0, home_away=1.0, Opp1_team=28.0, Tm_Pnts=6.0, Opp2_pnts=36.0, Off_1stD=16.0, Off_TotYd=232.0, Def_1stD_All=22.0, Def_TotYd_All=354.0)
Pandas(Index=(1, 2016), W=7.0, L=8.0, W_L_Pct=0.469, PD=56.0, MoV=3.5, SoS=-1.9, SRS=1.6, OSRS=2.4, DSRS=-0.8)
Pandas(Index=(1, 2016), Week=1, Date=Timestamp('2016-09-11 00:00:00'), win_loss=0.0, home_away=1.0, Opp1_team=21.0, Tm_Pnts=21.0, Opp2_pnts=23.0, Off_1stD=21.0, Off_TotYd=344.0, Def_1stD_All=19.0, Def_TotYd_All=363.0)
Pandas(Index=(1, 2016), Week=2, Date=Timestamp('2016-09-18 00:00:00'), win_loss=1.0, home_away=1.0, Opp1_team=30.0, Tm_Pnts=40.0, Opp2_pnts=7.0, Off_1stD=20.0, Off_TotYd=416.0, Def_1stD_All=21.0, Def_TotYd_All=306.0)
Pandas(Index=(1, 2016), Week=3, Date=Timestamp('2016-09-25 00:00:00'), win_loss=0.0, home_away=0.0, Opp1_team=4.0, Tm_Pnts=18.0, Opp2_pnts=33.0, Off_1stD=25.0, Off_TotYd=348.0, Def_1stD_All=16.0, Def_TotYd_All=297.0)
Pandas(Index=(1, 2016), Week=4, Date=Timestamp('2016-10-02 00:00:00'), win_loss=0.0, home_away=1.0, Opp1_team=18.0, Tm_Pnts=13.0, Opp2_pnts=17.0, Off_1stD=26.0, Off_TotYd=420.0, Def_1stD_All=12.0, Def_TotYd_All=288.0)
Pandas(Index=(1, 2016), Week=5, Date=Timestamp('2016-10-06 00:00:00'), win_loss=1.0, home_away=0.0, Opp1_team=29.0, Tm_Pnts=33.0, Opp2_pnts=21.0, Off_1stD=17.0, Off_TotYd=288.0, Def_1stD_All=25.0, Def_TotYd_All=286.0)
Pandas(Index=(1, 2016), Week=6, Date=Timestamp('2016-10-17 00:00:00'), win_loss=1.0, home_away=1.0, Opp1_team=24.0, Tm_Pnts=28.0, Opp2_pnts=3.0, Off_1stD=28.0, Off_TotYd=396.0, Def_1stD_All=11.0, Def_TotYd_All=230.0)
Pandas(Index=(1, 2016), Week=7, Date=Timestamp('2016-10-23 00:00:00'), win_loss=nan, home_away=1.0, Opp1_team=28.0, Tm_Pnts=6.0, Opp2_pnts=6.0, Off_1stD=23.0, Off_TotYd=443.0, Def_1stD_All=11.0, Def_TotYd_All=257.0)
Pandas(Index=(1, 2016), Week=8, Date=Timestamp('2016-10-30 00:00:00'), win_loss=0.0, home_away=0.0, Opp1_team=5.0, Tm_Pnts=20.0, Opp2_pnts=30.0, Off_1stD=22.0, Off_TotYd=340.0, Def_1stD_All=19.0, Def_TotYd_All=349.0)
Pandas(Index=(1, 2016), Week=10, Date=Timestamp('2016-11-13 00:00:00'), win_loss=1.0, home_away=1.0, Opp1_team=29.0, Tm_Pnts=23.0, Opp2_pnts=20.0, Off_1stD=26.0, Off_TotYd=443.0, Def_1stD_All=15.0, Def_TotYd_All=281.0)
Pandas(Index=(1, 2016), Week=11, Date=Timestamp('2016-11-20 00:00:00'), win_loss=0.0, home_away=0.0, Opp1_team=20.0, Tm_Pnts=24.0, Opp2_pnts=30.0, Off_1stD=24.0, Off_TotYd=290.0, Def_1stD_All=16.0, Def_TotYd_All=217.0)
Pandas(Index=(1, 2016), Week=12, Date=Timestamp('2016-11-27 00:00:00'), win_loss=0.0, home_away=0.0, Opp1_team=2.0, Tm_Pnts=19.0, Opp2_pnts=38.0, Off_1stD=23.0, Off_TotYd=332.0, Def_1stD_All=28.0, Def_TotYd_All=360.0)
Pandas(Index=(1, 2016), Week=13, Date=Timestamp('2016-12-04 00:00:00'), win_loss=1.0, home_away=1.0, Opp1_team=32.0, Tm_Pnts=31.0, Opp2_pnts=23.0, Off_1stD=24.0, Off_TotYd=369.0, Def_1stD_All=19.0, Def_TotYd_All=333.0)
Pandas(Index=(1, 2016), Week=14, Date=Timestamp('2016-12-11 00:00:00'), win_loss=0.0, home_away=0.0, Opp1_team=19.0, Tm_Pnts=23.0, Opp2_pnts=26.0, Off_1stD=21.0, Off_TotYd=300.0, Def_1stD_All=15.0, Def_TotYd_All=314.0)
Pandas(Index=(1, 2016), Week=15, Date=Timestamp('2016-12-18 00:00:00'), win_loss=0.0, home_away=1.0, Opp1_team=22.0, Tm_Pnts=41.0, Opp2_pnts=48.0, Off_1stD=26.0, Off_TotYd=425.0, Def_1stD_All=33.0, Def_TotYd_All=488.0)
Pandas(Index=(1, 2016), Week=16, Date=Timestamp('2016-12-24 00:00:00'), win_loss=1.0, home_away=0.0, Opp1_team=28.0, Tm_Pnts=34.0, Opp2_pnts=31.0, Off_1stD=21.0, Off_TotYd=370.0, Def_1stD_All=24.0, Def_TotYd_All=391.0)
Pandas(Index=(1, 2016), Week=17, Date=Timestamp('2016-01-01 00:00:00'), win_loss=1.0, home_away=0.0, Opp1_team=18.0, Tm_Pnts=44.0, Opp2_pnts=6.0, Off_1stD=21.0, Off_TotYd=344.0, Def_1stD_All=9.0, Def_TotYd_All=123.0)....
```

this is setup just how I would like each year starts with year avgs in a row followed by 17 rows of stats from each game that year.---now when I try to put into a DataFrame

```
new = pd.DataFrame(app, index=["Tm_name", "Year"])
AssertionError: 10 cols passed, passed data had 12 cols
```

could some one please help me iv been playing with this for 2 weeks, tried doing multi indexing, diff merges , concats, just can't seem to get it to look like the APP ARRAY and have no duplicates...

Thanks again

Comment: Why is there an R tag??

Comment: Look into `pd.DataFrame.merge()` function?

Comment: I have, I been playing with it for the better part of a week, that and multi index func                  ----no idea why there is an r tag, I only clicked on the python, pandas, DataFrame tags, must have highlighted the "R" tag somehow

Comment: Can you create some simple dataframes with the structures you're trying to merge?  Also, create the expected output.

Comment: think I should break it down to smaller dafarames then build them slowly from their, maybe adding a column1 by 1,,,, I was thinking to the df1 DF at a column "Weeks_games" then make the values of each cell a groupby objector df2 by year and team, is that possible ??